# How to request heart rate from sony lifelog api

Tags: sony, sony-lifelog-api

How can I request the heart rate (using smartband 2) from the lifelog API?

Answer (score 0):

If you need heart rate data from the SmartBand you can actually request it using the Google Fit API. You can find out more in this blog post:

https://developer.sony.com/2015/09/10/use-smartband-2-sensor-data-for-innovative-android-and-ios-applications/